# PHP not allowing insertion into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`crimereportingsystem`.`suspect`, CONSTRAINT `j_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`jail_id`) REFERENCES `jail` (`jail_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `suspect` (suspect_id, suspect_name, address, height, eye_colour, weight, plead_type, hair_colour, blood_group, gender, dob, jail_id, release_date, admission_date, lawyer_id, hire_type, Picture, fingerprint)
VALUES
('$suspect_id','$suspect_name','$address','$height','$eye_colour','$weight','$plead_type','$hair_colour', '$blood_group', '$gender', '$dob', '$jail_id', '$release', '$admission', '$lawyer_id', '$hire_type', '$picture', '$fingerprint') ";
```

Why does PHP throw the above error? What can i do?

Comment: It seems like you confusing server distributrion (xamp which uses php) with php itself. Are you sure you are using same database (connection and db)? Are you sure your $jail_id is same in both situations? Your error clearly sugest that there is no jail_id in jail table which you are trying to use in query ($jail_id). Please provide more info (full stack query)

Comment: I'm removing the XAMPP parts in the question. This is a PHP/MySQL issue.

Comment: which are the values you are trying to insert? the `jail_id` has a constraint, I guess its value must exist in another (jail?) table. Try echoing all the values before the insert, and check that all constraints are passed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have wrapped too many variables with apostrophes. Try to wrap only string-valued ones, and not numeric ones. I mean something like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO suspect (suspect_id, suspect_name, ...) 
VALUES 
($suspect_id, '$suspect_name', ...)";
```

Note that $suspect_id is **not** wrapped (I supposes it is an integer number), while $suspect_name is wrapped (I suppose it is a string).

Apply this idea to all variables. I hope this will work.